# CMFCEditBrowseCtrl crashes when Browse Mode set to Folder Browse

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to add a CMFCEditBrowseCtrl to a project that was upgraded from VC++ 6.0.  The Browse control works fine when Browse Mode is set to File Browse but gives a "Debug Assertion Failed...File:f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxeditbrowsectrl.cpp Line 550" error when Browse Mode is set to Folder Browse.

I also tried leaving the control set to File Browse in the resource editor and setting it to Folder Browse in the code through the use of the EnableFolderBrowseButton() function.  It causes the same problem.

I tried this in a simple sample app and it works fine so I compared the project settings of the two projects.  The only difference I find is in the C/C++ command line.  The project that crashes contains a "/D _VC80_UPGRADE=0x0600" entry.  I would like to remove this to see if that is the cause of the problem.  How can I do this?  Is this the cause of the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I seemed to have the same problem when calling EnableFolderBrowseButton, and Googled found this solution and it worked:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/483908/enablefolderbrowsebutton-assertion-failure

I should have searched the web a bit more before posting again. Here is the fix:

1. I had to change my App from a `CWinApp` to a `CWinAppEx`
2. I had to insert a call to `CWinAppEx::GetShellManager()` to my `InitInstance()`

It might help others if this were included as something to check in the HowTo that I referenced.

Comment: Link is dead (and not on archive.org).

Comment: You may also need to add #include <shlobj_core.h>
#include <afxeditbrowsectrl.h>.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you have a different WINVER. Or perhaps you have no manifest for your exe?

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have the same problem when calling `EnableFolderBrowseButton`, and Googled found this solution and it worked:

I do it by add this `line::InitInstance()`

```
CShellManager *pShellManager = new CShellManager;
```

and delete it in last line before `return false;`

```
if (pShellManager != nullptr){delete pShellManager;}
```